# Which is this date format and how to convert it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I'm importing a csv file and one of columns is a date, but it comes with this format:

```
date;
03 FEV;
03 FEV;
05 FEV;
07 FEV;
```

Which format is this? How to convert it to?

```
yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well that looks like it's only providing a day and month, with the month being abbreviated and in French, and with no year.

Comment: You have to know wich precise culture it is, otherwise parsing it is not really possible. I did a google search and "Fev" is the start of many Language variants for Feburary, it seems: https://www.omniglot.com/language/time/months.htm. But as John Said, this seems to be only the Date + Month. No mention of year or the elements of a full Datetime.

Comment: Ok, FEV references a brazilian language, february in this case...

Comment: It appears to be "dd MMM" but in a language other than English, e.g. French. As such, you'd use `Date.ParseExact` or `Date.TryParseExact` to convert to a `Date` and specify the appropriate format specifier and culture.

Comment: I believe that if you parse a `String` to a `Date` and there's no year specified then you'll get the current year by default.  You should do some reading and/or testing to confirm that.

Comment: It is all about providing the Proper Culture to teh Parse and ToString function. Normally it will just use the current culture (wich is retreived from Windows). Unless this is your local langauge, you will ahve to guess the culture and override it accordingly. it is all about getting the right Implementation of "IFormatProvider" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx)

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact(rows[0], "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", null);

This?

Comment: Not quite. You need the proper DateTimeFormatInformation for whatever culture you have as input. Here is a proper article on teh mater: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx#instantiating_Specific  Then you just pass it to this override of DateTime.Parse: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx

Comment: You were told that that format is "dd MMM" so how can "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" possibly work? Also, you should learn the difference between `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact`. Finally, what will be the culture on the system the code is run on? If it's not "pt-BR" then you need to specify that as the culture for the conversion.

Comment: You should read about the [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) methods as well as [date/time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Neither "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss" nor "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" make much sense and your proposed code wouldn't even compile..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date that only is "3rd Feburary" can only tell you that much. A DateTime will have to use something for the year and time, propably some default values. Keep that in mind. Also this is all asuming the Portugese Language - Brazilian Format. THe exact number formating can varry drastically, with few examples as clasical as en-US vs en-GB.

```
//Get the culture information you will need
CultureInfo cultureFormat = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR");
//Now let us try to Prase this
string input = "03 FEV";
DateTime output = DateTime.Parse(input, cultureFormat);
```

Comment: I wasn't sure that "dd MMM" would parse automatically, i.e. using `Parse` rather than `ParseExact`, but apparently it does.  Mind you, if you know for a fact that the format should be that and nothing else then I'd be tempted to use an "Exact" method anyway.